# I'm looking for the title of a sci fi film about a killer robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, space

I’m desperately trying to find the title of a film, but all of my online searches come up with nothing (it definitely exists though!)

The film's set in the future in space.  The synopsis seems to be that a guy is on the run (can’t remember from what), but he is also a murderer.  At some point, he mind melds/psychically programs a robot (perhaps a mining robot on a colony that he flees to to start a new life), and of course now the robot knows how to kill, and quite sadistically.

There are two iconic images that I remember in it:

1. To run away, the guy has to steal a spacecraft.  To do so, he walks into a space hanger, kind of like a dressing room, and gets into a space suit.  Other guys are milling around and getting out of their space suits.  Then, he hits a few levers and the roof opens.  The others freeze instantly, float out into space, and shatter on the roof beams.
2. When the killer robot’s on the loose, the inhabitants of the (mining?) colony are trapped in various different sectors.  They’re in contact on TV screens which show them each others faces.  One set of the groups gets a message from another guy on the TV screen, who assures them that everything is well and they should go to meet him.  The group goes, only to find that it’s a trap - the robot had decapitated the guy that they had just spoken to, and managed to wire up the head to make it talk, filming it to make it look like he was still alive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When did you view it and was it relatively new (or not) when you did ?  Theatrical release or made for TV ?  US or other ?

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83976/sci-fi-horror-movie-possessing-robot-with-long-neck (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 16):

*[Saturn 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079285/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_24)* (1980) with Farrah Fawcett, Kirk Douglas, and Harvey Keitel might be it.

> Two lovers stationed at a remote base in the asteroid fields of Saturn are intruded upon by a retentive technocrat from Earth and his charge: a malevolent eight foot robot.

### Trailer

Comment: No "might be" about it, that's definitely the film being described.  Big deal at the time because of a *very* brief topless scene by Farrah.

Comment: It's weird, arguably top actors or at least well known in case of Farah and I thought okay story and special effects and details of language spoken by Keitel but poorly reviewed. 2 of the stars still alive and one is over 100.