# Sci-Fi/Horror movie possessing robot with long neck

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, robots

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi/horror film from the late 70's or 80's. It was live-action and takes place mainly on a spaceship or station. The film is very dark with a vibe similar to Alien (1979). I don't remember the plot (other than people getting killed off one-by-one), but I do remember that the robot/android on the ship was distinctive:

- Humanoid body, black or dark gray in color
- long, extendable neck with a head on the end (think the lamp from Pixar's logo, only black)
- had a human brain, and may have had a psychotic break as a result (pretty sure the robot was doing the killing IIRC)

Sorry, I know this isn't much to go on, but that's exactly why I'm having problems finding it.

Comment: Sounds like Saturn 3 to me.

Comment: Great memory description of the robit, especially comparing it to the image posted below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like Cugel may have found it:

[Saturn 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_3) (1980), stars Farrah Fawcett, Kirk Douglas and Harvey Keitel.

> In the distant future, an overcrowded Earth relies on research
>   conducted by scientists in remote stations across the solar system.
>   One of these, a small experimental hydroponics research station on
>   Saturn's third moon *(called Saturn 3)*, is run solely by Adam
>   (Douglas) and his colleague and lover Alex (Fawcett).
>
> Alex and Adam's idyll is broken by the arrival of Captain Benson
>   (Keitel), who has been sent to Saturn 3 as part of a project to
>   replace at least one of the moon's scientists with a robot. Benson
>   assembles the robot and names him Hector. One of the first of its
>   kind, a "Demigod Series", Hector relies on "pure brain tissue"
>   extracted from human fetuses and programmed using a direct link to
>   Benson's brain. Benson states that it will render one of the crew
>   "obsolete", most likely Major Adam who tells his partner that he is
>   close to "abort time" according to the government on Earth.
>
> Unknown to both Alex and Adam, Benson is a homicidal sociopath who
>   murdered the captain originally assigned to Saturn 3 and took his
>   place on the mission. Benson had actually failed a crucial test of
>   psychological stability.
>
> As Benson uses the link to his brain to program the robot, Hector
>   acquires Benson's homicidal nature and his lust for Alex.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that looks like it. Gads, that robot creeps me out just as much now as it did then. Can't wait to watch it again LOL!